# Vimperator breaks delicious CTRL+D shortcut

Tags: firefox

How can I launch the "post to delicious" action (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in non-vimperator Firefox) with vimperator installed?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> as it does not require you to get out of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> mode (just kicks out of Vimperator for the keystroke which is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>).

Update: with the latest version of Vimperator, punch <kbd>i</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is now <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> (to lock it in).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I answered my own question:  pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> puts vimperator into "pass-through" mode, which allows key shortcuts to operate as expected.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> works.

Comment: yea, but that just makes it a tad complicated, is there no other way? Am thinking perhaps one can add an keyboard short cut exempt in the .vimperator file to perform the ordinary Ctrl-D to bookmark in delicious.

Comment: found a new solution look at my answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

To hack around the problem add this to your `.vimperatorrc` (this file is basically a configuration file like vimrc or bashrc, etc etc....if you still don't know what it is, google is your friend):

```
:set noremap <C-d> <C-z><C-d>
```

Basically the above remaps the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> key (used for delicious bookmarking) to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+D, so now with that setting in `.vimperator` you don't have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to bookmark.